# Login Redirect with router

Tags: php

I can't redirect to my main Page after the login

My structure:

```
views/auth/login.php <-- Thats my Login Page
public/index.php/ <-- router
https://sub.mydomain.de/auth/login <-- login url
https://sub.mydomain.de/ <-- url after Login
```

If the login was valid I want to redirect the user to this page `https://sub.mydomain.de/`

I tried:

```
header("/../../../public/index.php")
```

Comment: You need to redirect to the desired URL and then use the `mod_rewrite` to redirect everything to `public/index.php`

Comment: the router works fine but i need to change the header to the router default page

Comment: use header("Location:/../../../public/index.php")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing is fine, but one thing is missing here is `Location` in `header()`;

```
 `header("Location: /../../../public/index.php");`
```

you must define location in header!

Best place to learn some exciting things [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Happy Coding!